# Automatically Add Location, Class, to NetSuite Invoice Header based on other criteria

Tags: javascript, workflow, netsuite, invoice

When our staff make invoices for customers they fill out a lease number {custbody_es_lease} The lease record has the Property unit field (custom record) and that looks up the Property unit field on the invoice {custbody_es_property}

The Property unit record has the class {custrecord_es_pu_lease_fund_type} and the location {custrecord_location_on_property} that corresponds to the Property that's on the lease that is manually picked by the user.

I would like a workflow or script that when a user enters a lease number on the lease field, that it looks up the property record and automatically fills in the header location and class.

Would this be difficult to execute? And would a script added to the form be the best approach, or could I do it with a workflow?

Any sample would be great as well, let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

Comment: Invoice sources from Lease record which sources from Property record which sources from Invoice?

It sounds like you should be able to use a workflow to set the values {custbody_es_property.custrecord_location_on_property} for location and {custbody_es_property.custrecord_es_pu_lease_fund_type} for class.  

But this also sounds a lot like a request for someone to write a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks! It was shockingly easy to create a workflow for this.

Comment: @SheaBrennan Actually, I've run into a problem. Because class is a mandatory field, I set the workflow to before record submit, but it doesn't let me save the record without filling it out. Do you know if there's a way around that issue with a workflow? Or does that mean I have to go to a script? Thanks

Comment: Create a workflow that runs on the client-side.  That way everytime fields in you u logic changes you can change your values.